# Unable to open layout file

Tags: android

I am totally new in android. And i can not open to my layout xml file .
Anyone please help me.
this is my logcat show

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
>   Open File
> Show Details
>   Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
>   Open File
> Show Details

Comment: place complete error log here

Comment: Please update your **SDK** and **build.gradle** file.

Comment: post both of your module level and app level gradle files..